# How do I protect sheets with different options in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I am trying to protect sheets (visible only) in my Excel workbook in VBA.  I want to allow users to edit objects on "Sheet 2" and "Sheet 3", but not on the others.

This is the code I'm using.

```
Public Sub WBOpen()
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim allowObjects As Boolean
  For Each sh In Sheets
    If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
      **If sh.Name = "Sheet 2" Or "Sheet 3" Then**
        allowObjects = True
      Else
        allowObjects = False
      End If
      sh.Protect Password:=pw(sh), DrawingObjects:=allowObjects, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

I'm getting a type mismatch error on the line I've wrapped with **.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried: If sh.Name = "Sheet 2" Or sh.Name = "Sheet 3"

Comment: Also, be sure that the "Sheet 2" you refer to actually has a space when you look at the tab. By default, the tabs have no space (e.g. "Sheet2").

Comment: Randy - still getting the same error

Comment: Zairja - Yes the sheet names have spaces

Comment: Randy - OK I must have made a transpo error trying to affect your suggestion! It worked when I've tried it again. Thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line should be:

```
If sh.Name = "Sheet 2" Or sh.Name = "Sheet 3" Then
```

The type mismatch error comes because you are treating a string (`"Sheet 3"`) as a boolean (`True`/`False`).

Comment: Thanks for that. Also thanks to @Randy for offering this suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would still have an error after the error @Randy noted was fixed, but I can tell you what I do.  Instead of iterating through every sheet, I access the sheet I want to protect directly.  This is done by the *code* name, not the name in the GUI.  For example, in the VBA editor, in the Project Explorer, under the "Microsoft Excel Objects" folder, I click on my "Testing" sheet and see that it has a "(Name)" property of "TestingSheet".  Note that this is probably just an optional step, for clarity, as my other sheets have names too - like "Sheet1".  Then in the code I just type:

```
TestingSheet.Protect , True, True, True, True
```

If you did this, you would avoid the runtime error, and you would also be more flexible in terms of the GUI name of the worksheets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll bear your comments in mind for future development.